# "Could you please let me know if there is any team looking for an intern willing to start immediately?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to say: "Could you please let me know if there is any team looking for an intern willing to start immediately?"

Thanks
Rgds,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version is fine. Here's another version, which is simpler and more specific:

> "Are there any teams looking for an intern who is ready to start immediately?"

- "Could you please let me know..." can be removed as it is implied by the question itself.
- "... if there is any team..." makes more sense, being in singular form, if your question is going to one person, such as the manager of all teams.
- "... if there are any teams..." makes more sense, being in plural form, if your question is going to all teams.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine.  It could have been written by a native speaker.

The slight ambiguity about whether the intern or the team is to start immediately does make the reader think for a millisecond, so you could add "who is" after "intern" and take an ounce off the reader's load.

The notion that **making the reader think unnecessarily is bad writing** will help you over the long term.